Particular endpoint in a controller gives 401 Unauthorized error while others in the same controller don't
package com.hexa.amazecare.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.hexa.amazecare.dto.DoctorDTO;
import com.hexa.amazecare.service.DoctorService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/doctors")
public class DoctorController {

    @Autowired
    private DoctorService doctorService;

    // Get doctor by ID
    @GetMapping("/get/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<DoctorDTO> getDoctorById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        DoctorDTO doctorDTO = doctorService.getDoctorById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(doctorDTO);
    }
    
    //get doctors by Specialty
    @GetMapping("/get-specialty/{speciality}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<DoctorDTO>> getDoctorBySpecality(@PathVariable String specialty) {
        List<DoctorDTO> doctors = doctorService.getDoctorBySpecality(specialty);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(doctors);
    }

    // Endpoint to get all doctors
    @GetMapping("/get")
    public ResponseEntity<List<DoctorDTO>> getAllDoctors() {
        List<DoctorDTO> doctors = doctorService.getAllDoctors();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(doctors);
    }

    // Create a new doctor
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<DoctorDTO> createDoctor(@RequestBody DoctorDTO doctorDTO) {
        DoctorDTO newDoctor = doctorService.createDoctor(doctorDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(newDoctor);
    }

    // Update an existing doctor
    @PutMapping("update/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<DoctorDTO> updateDoctor(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody DoctorDTO doctorDTO) {
        DoctorDTO updatedDoctor = doctorService.updateDoctor(id, doctorDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedDoctor);
    }

    // Delete a doctor by ID
    @DeleteMapping("delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteDoctor(@PathVariable Long id) {
        doctorService.deleteDoctor(id);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
    
 // Endpoint to retrieve all specialties
    @GetMapping("/specialties")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getAllSpecialties() {
        List<String> specialties = doctorService.getAllSpecialties();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(specialties);
    }
}

So I have these endpoints in a doctor controller class, while all the endpoints work after authorization perfectly, the "getDoctorBySpecality" endpoint doesn't give appropriate result. It gives a 401 unauthorized error.
Here's my security config for further context:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll() // Allow access to registration and login
                .requestMatchers("api/patients/get/**").hasAnyRole("DOCTOR","PATIENT","ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/api/patients/**").hasAnyRole("PATIENT","DOCTOR","ADMIN") 
                .requestMatchers("/api/doctors/get-specialty/").hasAnyRole("DOCTOR","PATIENT","ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/api/doctors/**").hasAnyRole("DOCTOR","PATIENT","ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // All other requests require authentication
            )
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
}

I tried accessing my endpoint from my Postman and got the 401 unauthorized error. I am a beginner at Spring Boot, so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Always use /** at the end of a matcher like you did for the other endpoints when you want to allow access to routes that include additional segments, eg {id}
Here you missed /**:
.requestMatchers("/api/doctors/get-specialty/").hasAnyRole("DOCTOR","PATIENT","ADMIN")

It should be:
.requestMatchers("/api/doctors/get-specialty/**").hasAnyRole("DOCTOR","PATIENT","ADMIN")

Also
@GetMapping("/get-specialty/{speciality}")
public ResponseEntity<List<DoctorDTO>> getDoctorBySpecality(@PathVariable String specialty) {
    List<DoctorDTO> doctors = doctorService.getDoctorBySpecality(specialty);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(doctors);
}

You have a typo in the path - {speciality} change to {specialty}.

Hey Thank you for your Response! I've tried that but it didn't resolve the issue. But I've found a new clue to the issue
When I try to access the endpoint I get the following error in my console:
2024-10-04T23:05:15.907+05:30[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m18748[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[AmazeCare] [nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Required URI template variable 'specialty' for method parameter type String is not present]

This is the example url which I used http://localhost:8080/api/doctors/get-specialty/"cardiology"

Updated my answer U got a typo. @GetMapping("/get-specialty/{speciality}")

Try changing:
.requestMatchers("/api/doctors/get-specialty/").hasAnyRole("DOCTOR","PATIENT","ADMIN")

to
.requestMatchers("/api/doctors/get-specialty").hasAnyRole("DOCTOR","PATIENT","ADMIN")

